# How to disable the WPF ScrollViewer to refresh the view

Tags: wpf, user-interface, scroll, scrollview, freeze

I am using a stack panel for displaying a slideshow. The stack panel contains two images.
Each image is bound to the View Model containing among other properties the path to the image on the disk. In the general case there are more than 2 images in the list.
There is an endless while loop used for changing the current and next pointer to the image and in this way after the slide transition is finished the the current image becomes previous and the next becomes current.
The slide transition is made by changing the scroll viewer from 0 to 100% of scrollable extended area.

This works and even very fast.  It is the easiest way to implement a slide transition for an endless list of images using MVVM pattern.
My problem is that from time to time the slide transition slips and doesn't finishes at exact 100% visually but the storyboard animation completed event is triggered.
In the ViewModel I am moving the Current and Next poitners and the image blinks. Some flickering is visible from time to time.

I need to find a way on how to temporarily disable the ScrollViewer to display any visual change when I am repositioning the scoller from 100% to 0%.

I need to invalidate the WPF ScrollViewer only temporarily until I change the scroll position from 100% to 0% but this must not be visible on screen.

I mean the values must be changed but the screen must be frozen.

Is it possible somehow ?

**XAML**

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard  x:Key="sbVerticalSlideEasingTransition"
                 AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever">

    <Storyboard  x:Key="sbVerticalSlideTransition"
                FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
        <!--SCROLL TO THE MULTIPLIER OF THE HEIGHT (BASICALLY AS THE PERCENTAGE)-->
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                            Storyboard.TargetName="Mediator"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScrollableHeightMultiplier">
                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:0:0" Value="0" />
                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:0:5" Value="1" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>

</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="gdContainer" Background="Black">
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="Scroller"  Visibility="{Binding Path=IsSlider, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, ElementName=slidePlayer,
                                                    Converter='{StaticResource BoolToVisibility}'}"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <StackPanel x:Name="ScrollPanel">
            <ctrl:MediaElementEx x:Name="slide1"  Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=gdContainer}" Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=gdContainer}" />
            <ctrl:MediaElementEx x:Name="slide2"  Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=gdContainer}" Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=gdContainer}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>

    <!-- Mediator that forwards the property changes -->
    <cmn:ScrollViewerOffsetMediator x:Name="Mediator" ScrollViewer="{Binding ElementName=Scroller}"/>

</Grid>
```

**ScrollViewer Mediator**

This is used to bind the ScrollOffset of the scrollviewer that is not bindable directly

```
    /// <summary>
/// Mediator that forwards Offset property changes on to a ScrollViewer
/// instance to enable the animation of Horizontal/VerticalOffset.
/// </summary>
public class ScrollViewerOffsetMediator : FrameworkElement
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ScrollViewer instance to forward Offset changes on to.
    /// </summary>
    public ScrollViewer ScrollViewer
    {
        get { return (ScrollViewer)GetValue(ScrollViewerProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ScrollViewerProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollViewerProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ScrollViewer",
            typeof(ScrollViewer),
            typeof(ScrollViewerOffsetMediator),
            new PropertyMetadata(OnScrollViewerChanged));
    private static void OnScrollViewerChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mediator = (ScrollViewerOffsetMediator)o;
        var scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)(e.NewValue);
        if (null != scrollViewer)
        {
            scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(mediator.VerticalOffset);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// VerticalOffset property to forward to the ScrollViewer.
    /// </summary>
    public double VerticalOffset
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(VerticalOffsetProperty); }
        set { SetValue(VerticalOffsetProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty VerticalOffsetProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "VerticalOffset",
            typeof(double),
            typeof(ScrollViewerOffsetMediator),
            new PropertyMetadata(OnVerticalOffsetChanged));
    public static void OnVerticalOffsetChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mediator = (ScrollViewerOffsetMediator)o;
        if (null != mediator.ScrollViewer)
        {
            mediator.ScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset((double)(e.NewValue));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// HorizontalOffset property to forward to the ScrollViewer.
    /// </summary>
    public double HorizontalOffset
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(HorizontalOffsetProperty); }
        set { SetValue(VerticalOffsetProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HorizontalOffsetProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "HorizontalOffset",
            typeof(double),
            typeof(ScrollViewerOffsetMediator),
            new PropertyMetadata(OnHorizontalOffsetChanged));
    public static void OnHorizontalOffsetChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mediator = (ScrollViewerOffsetMediator)o;
        if (null != mediator.ScrollViewer)
        {
            mediator.ScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset((double)(e.NewValue));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Multiplier for ScrollableHeight property to forward to the ScrollViewer.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// 0.0 means "scrolled to top"; 1.0 means "scrolled to bottom".
    /// </remarks>
    public double ScrollableHeightMultiplier
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ScrollableHeightMultiplierProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ScrollableHeightMultiplierProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollableHeightMultiplierProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ScrollableHeightMultiplier",
            typeof(double),
            typeof(ScrollViewerOffsetMediator),
            new PropertyMetadata(OnScrollableHeightMultiplierChanged));
    public static void OnScrollableHeightMultiplierChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mediator = (ScrollViewerOffsetMediator)o;
        var scrollViewer = mediator.ScrollViewer;
        if (null != scrollViewer)
        {
            scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset((double)(e.NewValue) * scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight);
            if (((double)e.NewValue == 0) && ((double)e.OldValue == 1))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("[1] {0:HH:mm:ss.fff} ScrollableHeightMultiplier 1 => 0 ", DateTime.Now);
            }
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Multiplier for ScrollableWidth property to forward to the ScrollViewer.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// 0.0 means "scrolled to top"; 1.0 means "scrolled to bottom".
    /// </remarks>
    public double ScrollableWidthMultiplier
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ScrollableWidthMultiplierProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ScrollableWidthMultiplierProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollableWidthMultiplierProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ScrollableWidthMultiplier",
            typeof(double),
            typeof(ScrollViewerOffsetMediator),
            new PropertyMetadata(OnScrollableWidthMultiplierChanged));
    public static void OnScrollableWidthMultiplierChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mediator = (ScrollViewerOffsetMediator)o;
        var scrollViewer = mediator.ScrollViewer;
        if (null != scrollViewer)
        {
            scrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset((double)(e.NewValue) * scrollViewer.ScrollableWidth);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. If you upload your project or a demo somewhere online I will gladly download it and provide you with a solution. If you want to upload code here please split the code in xaml, code behind, viewmodel and data and post it in paragraphs. :)

Comment: Thank you. I will need to split the project in parts because it is complex. One idea to try that will be to not raise the OnPropertyChanged event at the specific times or even to disable the binding temporarily.

Comment: Or you use DelayBinding. http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-delaybinding If your project is too complex please take pieces out of it and create a demo or simply stick them as they are in your post. We will need just small details anyways like how you defined your XAML and what are you doing with your animations/handlers.

Comment: Yes it is complex and doesn't happen often. Only from time to time but for sure is a problem of synchronization.

Comment: Well, please just post most important pieces such as how you defined your Slider and that StackPanel and how you changing images when moving Slider...

Comment: Yes one moment... need to extract the important parts of the view-model